# What kind of db is used in Vignette CMS

Tags: content-management-system, vignette

In our enterprise app, we are using Vignette for CMS. And the CMS page content is saved to some sort of db. Now while Vignette setup,I did not see any setup of an external db (like Oracle). So I am guessing the db is built insdie the Vignette. Any idea how this is implemented in Vignette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OpenText Web Experience Management (formerly Vignette Content Management) Supports Oracle, SQL Server, DB2
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems